# JQuery AJAX call with multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to pass two parameters in dataString of JQuery AJAX call. I have tried but not working.How to retrieve these parameters in the page which is requested by ajax call. Can anyone help me

```js
function update_status(status,supplier,id){
           dataString = "status=" + status + "&supplier=" + supplier;
           alert(dataString);
            $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax_status.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            
                            $("#status_" + id).text(data);


                        }
                    });
            
            
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work perfect, look how i add the data.

```
function update_status(status,supplier,id){
    $.ajax
        ({
             type: "POST",
             url: "ajax_status.php",
             data: {status: status, supplier: supplier},
             cache: false,
             success: function(data)
                 {
                     $("#status_" + id).text(data);
                 }
             });
        }
```